# Unpacking two huge lists in python

Tags: sql, django, python-2.7

I have two huge lists in python. lets say

```
countries = ['country names'.....]
country_codes = ['ccd' .....]
```

I am trying to use for loop to unpack the data and load it into database, but I am getting an error

> "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

need help ...

Comment: Or should I use an Iterator here... or is there any other method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include your code so it's easier to see the error. My guess is you didn't zip the lists together :

```
for country, code in zip(countries, country_codes):
    #insert country, code into db
```